# ParseFacebookUtilsV4 and Facebook-iOS-SDK 4.0

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I have updated my project to use the newest releases of Parse and Facebook SDKs and I have a question.

To use Facebook with Parse, we have to call `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:]` and in Facebook SDK, `[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`. Since both are pretty similar, I was wondering if we have to call both or not.

In my app I'm calling only the PFFacebookUtils method and so far it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to call `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:]` and the underlying call to `[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` is handled by Parse.